# How to query meteor-mongo on value, not _id or key

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I am creating a meteor app that gets sensor data from remote devices via POST, and need to query on a value in a mongo collection, returning the document _id.

The document is similar to this:

```
[{
    _id: 0,
    device: {
        mac: 'XXX', // always unique
        sd1: nnn,
        sd2: nnn,
        ...
    }
}]
```

I need to be able to do a findOne() on **XXX**, determine if it exists, and get the _id of the corresponding doc.

I've tried variations of `collection.findOne({}, {mac: 1})`, but that only returns the first document that contains the *key* 'mac'. As every doc will contain that key (but the value will always be unique), this is pretty useless as it always returns the first document in the collection. I need to query on the *value* of the key.

There must be a very obvious solution, but it has eluded me thus far.

Comment: The result snippet that you've provided.. is it a part of a larger mongo document? Or is it the entire document. I'm asking because I noticed it within an array  ```[ {....} ]```

Comment: Yes, this is just a fragment. I think I have a solution: findOne({'device.mac': 'XXX'}); from meteor forums.